# php5 odbc_connect() function error when connecting to Visual FoxPro9 table

Tags: php, linux, odbc, visual-foxpro

I'm running php5 on Ubuntu10.10 server where the unixODBC and php5-odbc packages have already been installed.  I keep getting an error during the connection process - code:

```
$data_source = 'DRIVER={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};Data Source=//128.251.xxx.xxx/lv_apps/AppsLON/CData/dbf/cdma';"", "");
$conn = odbc_connect($data_source, "", "");
if (!$conn)
    exit("Connection Failed: " .$conn );
```

error message:

```
1 Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in /var/www/vfptest.php on line 6
```

I added `extention=dbase.so` and `extention=odbc.so` to both files: `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and re-compiled the php install with:

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-dbase=shared --with-unixODBC
```

I've also gone to unixODBC and pecl to install the unixODBC and dbase libraries separately with no luck.

Also I found this link: http://www.devlist.com/ConnectionStringsPage.aspx
where it is stated that in order to create an ODBC connection to a foxpro database I use the line:

```
Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBC;SourceDB=c:\demo.dbc;Exclusive=No;NULL=NO;Collate=Machine;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;DELETED=NO
```

this still did not work for me however; probably because I do not have the visual foxpro driver installed or my odbc.ini file pointing to the driver path...but I don't know.

Comment: also see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716492/php5-access-visual-foxpro-9-tables

Answer (score 1):

In short - odbc_connect() takes; an ODBC Data Source Name (DSN), Username & Password as per --

http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

As far as I am aware there is no VFP ODBC driver for Linux so you will, most likely, need to employ an ODBC Bridge solution like -

http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-odbc-mt/

This has a client/server architecture --

Linux client --
  php ODBC Application
  OpenLink Generic ODBC Driver (thin multi-tier ODBC client)

Windows server --
  OpenLink Request Broker (Multi-tier server)
  OpenLInk Agent for ODBC (Multi-tier server)
  Fox Pro ODBC DSN (pre configured)
  Fox Pro files...

I hope this helps?

Comment: I believe VFP is supported under the dBASE driver.  That being the case what is my syntax structure - also which additional files/dll's or php.ini extentions do I need to allow dBASE functions to work?

Comment: @sadmicrowave, I can't really comment re: dBASE and VFP compatibility.

Comment: @sadmicrowave, Suffice it to say, php's odbc_connect() function takes either a Data Source Name (DSN) or an ODBC Connection String (in the case of a DSN'less connection as DRapp posted).

Your fundamental problems is twofold -

1) You are not providing neither a DSN or connection string.

2) You do not have an ODBC driver installed providing the connectivity you require

This is quite a large topic - too much for 200 character responses so please feel free to mail me at gbiggs@<nospam>openlinksw.com

Answer (score 1):

Check out the very bottom of this thread on the [MSDN network](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/visualfoxprogeneral/thread/821a3cb7-2f25-4cc9-b3a6-ec4551013d2a)

the driver line you have posted is "...an ODBC connection string which is not supported for VFP tables having a version later than 6."

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. What if I use a different method like dBASE then?

Comment: Depends which *nix version you are using.  Ubuntu doesn't come with DBASE by default, so you have some apt-get and configuring to do: [link]http://www.calipus.com/blogs/install-and-configure-php-dbase-ubuntu-1010-and-php-5210

Answer (score 0):

Although not familiar with linux connecting to VFP, however, odbc connections for such VFP connect to a PATH, not a specific table.  Once the connection to the PATH is valid, THEN you can query any .DBF table IN that location.

Although I can't answer your specific connection info, I've found this link

http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=296832.0

that shows connecting to a datasource... notice its identifying the 'DRIVER={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};datasource=/home/dir/file.dbf;' used... You'll probably have to hit a combination of this driver and pathing info (I'd still try WITHOUT the specific .dbf file first).

Hope this helps..

Comment: please see my OP for an Update pretaining to your suggestions